# Elasticsearch 5 connector in Apache Flink 1.4

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I'm a newbie to Flink, I'm trying to play with ElasticSearch connector but without success.
I installed ElasticSearch 5.5, Kibana, and Flink 1.4 on Docker.

Here is my code:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

while java code is:

```
DataStream<String> consumer = .....

    consumer.print();

    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster");
    config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");

    List<InetSocketAddress> transports = new ArrayList<>();
    transports.add(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300));

    consumer.addSink(new ElasticsearchSink<>(config, transports, new ElasticsearchSinkFunction<String>() {
        public IndexRequest createIndexRequest(String element) {
            Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<>();
            json.put("id", "2");
            return Requests.indexRequest()
                    .index("signinindex").type("signin").source(json);
        }

        public void process(String element, RuntimeContext ctx, RequestIndexer indexer) {
            indexer.add(createIndexRequest(element));
        }
    }));

    env.execute();
```

But when I try to submit a new job in IDE, it seems to stay waiting, so I'm wondering if there are some problems with ElasticSearch 5.5 which conflicts with Flink.
Thanks a lot.

[UPDATE]: I made some tests with ES 5.1.2 and now when submitting my jar I receive the following exception (I tried to upgrade Flink to 1.4.1 with all connectors too):

```
    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not run the jar.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleJsonRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not run the jar.
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[]) method from the class ProtoSignInMap: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:495)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarActionHandler.getJobGraphAndClassLoader(JarActionHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleJsonRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:69)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:489)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

Obviously the main method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink currently supports Elasticsearch up to version 5.1.x. For more info see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7386

Comment: Hi Dawid,
thanks for your answer, I just updated my question

Comment: @user2007820 remember that the jar that you submit should be an uber jar that also contains all necessary dependencies. Also please do not extend initial question on SO, as the question may grow quite large.